# Hello World Java Servlet doesn't work

Tags: servlets, amazon-ec2

I'm using amazon's EC2, and I'm trying to run this tutorial
http://helloworldprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/servlet-hello-world.html

When applying the command:

> javac -cp .........\lib\servlet-api.jar test\HelloServlet.java

(with the appropriate path of course) i'm getting the following errors:
[image: Errors]

Also, we are using apache-tomcat-6.0.33, but when entering http://localhost:8080/ the version of apache is 6.0.32.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanx

Comment: Not convinced it *is* the right path, otherwise it'd be able to find the library. Do you really have a directory called `usr/apache-tomcat...etc.` in your `classes` output directory?! If so, you really shouldn't. Also, please cut-and-paste errors rather than posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler didn't find you servlet-api.jar.
Try to use a absolute path to this file,
maybe you can use a simple path like /tmp/servlet-api.jar.

Your tomcat is in user's home?
Why you are using '.' on the path's start?